# What is rank of $f(A)$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f(x)$ is minimal polynomial of the $4\times 4$ matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &0& 1\\
1 &0 &0 &0\\ 
0 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then what is rank of $f(A)$? I think $f(A)$ will be a zero matrix so its rank is 0. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, that's exactly right...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264387/what-is-rank-of-fa-where-f-is-the-minimal-polynomial-of-a#comment577701_264387)  $\phantom{ok I'll add a little random text here to avoid automatic conversion}{}{}$

Answer (score -1):

From the definition of minimal polynomial $f(A)=0.$ Hence $f(A)$ is the zero transformation. Hence rank is $0.$